# need an explanation of python packages and modules

Tags: python

I am writing my first python script and this package/module thing has me going nuts.  Lets start with my folder layout

```
builder.py
-buildModule\__init__.py
-buildModule\AppList.py
-buildModule\BuildClass.py
-buildModule\ConfigSystem.py
-buildModule\MenuSystem.py
-buildModule\Singleton.py
```

ok, so my `__init__.py` looks like this

```
from ConfigSystem import *
from BuildClass import *
from MenuSystem import *
from AppList import *
from buildModule.Singleton import Singleton
```

Now, im trying to decorate my configsystem as a singleton so my singleton looks like

```
class Singleton:
    def __init__(self, decorated):
        self._decorated = decorated

    def Instance(self):
        try:
            return self._instance
        except AttributeError:
            self._instance = self._decorated()
            return self._instance

    def __call__(self):
        raise TypeError(
            'Singletons must be accessed through the `Instance` method.')
```

and now, with my configsystem class, if im reading the manual correctly, this should work

```
import Singleton


@Singleton
class ConfigSystem:
```

but im getting

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've read the module part of the manual several times now and im not quite getting it.  Why isn't this working?

Is there a module/package tutorial out there somewhere that is written a bit clearer/differently than the manual?

Comment: Why is `ConfigSystem` the name of a module AND the name of a class?  Isn't that going to be confusing?  Could you change one of those names?  It would almost eliminate your `'module' object is not callable` error.

Comment: try "from Singleton import Singleton". Your imported Singleton is not a class but a module. That is what your error message says.

Comment: @scphantm Hey, that's _my_ singleton implementation. [Character for character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558/python-and-the-singleton-pattern/7346105#7346105). :D I'm glad you found it useful but beware: it doesn't work if you later want to inherit from that singleton.

Comment: yea paul, i found it here.  still trying to get used to this multiple classes in one file thing.  after working in java exclusively for 9 years, its quite a change going to something like python.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `import Singleton` to `from Singleton import Singleton` (or as Alex suggested change `@Singleton` to `@Singleton.Singleton`.

In general you should use qualified imports to avoid namespace collisions, e.g., `import SomeModule` with a call like `SomeModule.SomeClass` or for brevity something like `import SomeModule as SM` with a call like `SM.SomeClass` or `SM.some_function` rather than importing everything from a module like `from SomeModule import *`.

You have name collisions, where `Singleton` is referring to the module (e.g., `Singleton.py` a file that is a collection of classes/functions/variables) rather than the Singleton class (`class Singleton(object)`).  Specifically, in your decorator `@Singleton` `Singleton` is referring to the module (you `import some_module` or `from some_module import a_class_or_object`) rather than a class or function.

Answer (score 2):

Either change `import Singleton` to `from Singleton import Singleton`, or change `@Singleton` to `@Singleton.Singleton`.