# does __init__ get called multiple times with this implementation of Singleton? (Python)

Tags: python, singleton, init

Source: [Python and the Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558/python-and-the-singleton-pattern)

According to most upvoted comment in the top answer **init** gets called multiple times if **new** returns class instance.

So I checked this:

```
class Singleton(object):

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'Singleton.__new__ called with class', cls
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class Cache(Singleton):

    def __init__(self, size=100):
        print 'I am called with size', size


class S(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, param):
        print 'I am S with param', param


c = Cache(20)
s = S(10)
```

Result:

```
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.Cache'>
I am called with size 20
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.S'>
I am S with param 10
```

Apparently **init** does not called more than once in a class inheriting from Singleton. Has smth changed in Python that handles this in the meantime (considering the question was asked in 2008), or am I missing smth here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your two last lines with

```
for x in range(5):
    c = Cache(x)
    s = S(x)
```

and post the result.

Comment: Now I get it, I thought they were talking about some inheritance magic and did not think of a simple thing..  Anyway pls take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386562/python-singleton-take-2 too

Answer (score 0):

From the print result it is obvious that `__init__` is called upon construction of each new `Cache` and `S` object.

When you create an instance of a class (eg `Cache(10)`) Python first creates a new instance of it using `__new__` then initializes it using `__init__`.

In other words apparently you misread something.