# Python singleton, take 2

Tags: python, singleton

Read this first pls: [does __init__ get called multiple times with this implementation of Singleton? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383970/does-init-get-called-multiple-times-with-this-implementation-of-singleton/)

```
class Singleton(object):

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'Singleton.__new__ called with class', cls
        if not cls._instance:
            print 'Singleton.__new__ creating instance of class', cls
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Cache(Singleton):

    def __init__(self, size=100):
        print 'Cache.__init__ called with size', size



for x in range(5):
    c = Cache(x)
```

Result:

```
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.Cache'>
Singleton.__new__ creating instance of class <class '__main__.Cache'>
Cache.__init__ called with size 0
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.Cache'>
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.Cache'>
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.Cache'>
Singleton.__new__ called with class <class '__main__.Cache'>
```

It seems to work now, but the question is whether calling inhering class **init** explicitly in Singleton is pythonic? Is there smth that might go wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work. You never actually return anything from `__new__`, so it returns the default value of `None`. `cls._instance` is set properly, but you don't get `cls._instance` when you call `Cache`.

Comment: this is getting personal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386776/python-singleton-take-3