# Python: __init__ of derived Singleton not called

Tags: python, singleton, new-operator, init, derived

I was toying around with the Singleton pattern and derivation. Specifically, I had this code:

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None
    init_attempts = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.init_attempts += 1
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class Derived(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attribute = "this is derived"


def main():
    instance_1 = Singleton()
    instance_2 = Singleton()

    print("instance_1 and instance_2 are ", end="")
    if id(instance_1) == id(instance_2):
        print("the ame")
    else:
        print("different")
    
    derived_instance = Derived()
    print("derived_instance and instance_2 are the same:", derived_instance is instance_2)
    
    try:
        print(derived_instance.attribute)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Initialization of Derived has been prevented")
    
    print("Number of initializations:", derived_instance.init_attempts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To my surprise, the `__init__` of Derived is never called, i.e. `derived_instance.attribute` does not exist and `derived_instance.init_attempts` remains `2`.
As I understand it, `SomeClass()` is resolved to `SomeClass.__call__()`, which in turn should call the `__new__` and `__init__` methods. Yet, in the above example, `Derived.__init__` is never called.

In detail, my output is:

```
instance_1 and instance_2 are the ame
derived_instance and instance_2 are the same: True
Initialization of Derived has been prevented
Number of initializations: 2
```

Can anybody explain to me, why that is?
In particular, the similar example here:
[How to initialize Singleton-derived object once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789235/how-to-initialize-singleton-derived-object-once)
works as expected, i.e. `Tracer` triggers printing `init` twice.

I am aware that deriving from Singletons cannot be done in a meaningful way, and that both, a Singleton decorator and metaclass exist and how to use them, so I'm specifically interested in how the inheritance process goes awry. I presume it has something to do with the MRO, but I cannot think of anything that would not also compromise the Tracer example from the link.

I tried finding similar links, but could not find any additional information.

This here asks a very similar question:
[does __init__ get called multiple times with this implementation of Singleton? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383970/does-init-get-called-multiple-times-with-this-implementation-of-singleton)
but doesn't answer it, or rather only confirms that a derived class' ´__init__´ should get called as well.

Thanks in advance! Hoping to pay back the favour soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) has the answer:

> If `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an
> instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method
> will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where *self* is the new instance
> and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to the object constructor.
>
> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s
> `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

In the case at hand, when `Derived()` (which has no `__new__` of its own) is called to create a class instance, `Singleton.__new__` is invoked, and because that *does not return an instance of* `Derived` (but of `Singleton`), the *`__init__()` method will not be invoked.*

Comment: The fact that `Derived` doesn't have its own `__new__` isn't all that relevant. The "problem" is that even if `cls` is `Derived`, `cls._instance` will see `Singleton._instance` (because inheritance), and thus no new instance of `Derived` will be created.

Comment: That depends; if `Derived` had its own `__new__` which would `return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`, an instance of `Derived` would be created and `Derived.__init__()` would be called as well.

Comment: But then it won't be a singleton, because there will be different instances for `Singleton` and `Derived`.