# SIngleton class does not retain value

Tags: python, singleton

First of all i would like to state that i am fairly new to Python programming, therefore my approach to solving the problem maybe incorrect, please let me know if that is the case

I am trying to use a Singleton class to store configuration params in my code and use it when needed. I run into an issue that the data stored in the Singleton in the initial creation is not retained in the subsequent calls to the Object.

Maybe the way i create the Singleton object is incorrect, but i was following the code samples that was on SO.

first here is my Singleton class

```
class Config(object):

    __instance = None

    dbserver = ""

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance == None:
            __instance = object.__new__(cls)
            __instance.name = "Configuration Object"
        return __instance
```

Here is my initial creation of the Singleton instance

```
configurator = Config()
configurator.dbserver = dbserver
```

then subsequently i do the following and `dbserver` property returns empty string.

```
configurator = Config()
print configurator.dbserver
```

Thanks for your time reading.

Comment: Is it same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558/python-and-the-singleton-pattern

Comment: `cls.__instance` is always `None`, so every time new object is getting created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to be assigning the local variable `__instance` to the class variable `cls.__instance`.

However, if you're just doing this to store variables, I don't know why you need an instance at all. Just store them directly on the class - which is itself a first-class object in Python - or even use a module, which is more Pythonic.

**Edit**

Using the class itself wouldn't cause the code to be re-run each time: code at class level is only executed when the class is **defined**, which happens on first import.

But since the class has to live in a module (a file) somewhere, you could just as easily put all that code directly in the module, and import that where you need it. Again, code at module level is only executed on first import.

Comment: i am reading the configuration from a config file and storing in the class at run time, but i see what your suggesting i could use the class it self to read the variables from config file and have it available. But if i don't use a singleton object it would have to re-read the config file everytime i use it? can you please elaborate more on the Pythonic approach you were suggesting

Comment: so your saying instead of creating the config file, use a class as the config file it self?