# Real world example of overriding __new__ method in Python

Tags: python, class

I'm familiar with the theory about `__new__` vs `__init__`. The former one defines how an instance of a class is created (new object inside the memory), whereas the latter one initializes it (assigns initial state attributes - fields). There is a couple of articles in the web about this, such as [this one](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061426.html):

> Use `__new__` when you need to control the creation of a new instance.
>   Use `__init__` when you need to control initialization of a new
>   instance.

As I said, I do understand the difference, yet, I can't imagine a real world example of situation when I need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`. If I can customize something during object creation, I can move it to object initialization - as long as it's the same object. The mentioned link says:

> In general, you shouldn't need to override `__new__` unless you're
>   subclassing an immutable type like str, int, unicode or tuple.

And here comes my question - can someone give an example of situation, when overriding `__new__` is in fact the right solution that can't be done using `__init__` and why is that?

Comment: [Subclassing Python tuple with multiple \_\_init\_\_ arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565374)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the link, but anyway, I'd appreciate a real world example. I guess that when you create an immutable tuple, you can do nothing with it inside __init__ since it's immutable by definition.

Comment: `__new__` is also useful when you have to do C level allocations. For example, you may have a pool of unused objects, expensive to initialize, so when you need a new one you just grab it from there instead of creating a full new one.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: "Real-world": https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple Yes, you need `__new__` because by the time the instance is created it can no longer be changed.

Comment: Another one: [Python and the Singleton Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42558)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Singletone pattern** - the most obvious example.
When you've created one more object - it is not the singletone, right?
Thus, you have to handle this when you're creating your object. One variant of the solution - to use `__new__()` method.

Comment: example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558/python-and-the-singleton-pattern)