# What syntax is better for python != or is not?

Tags: python

For example:

```
match = re.search('...', str, re.IGNORECASE)
if match is not None:
    pass

# or
if match != None:
    pass
```

What is better?

Comment: Neither is better, since they differ in behaviour.

Comment: `is` is an identity operator, so it should be used ONLY when checking if the object has the _same_ memory address (singletons such as None qualify). Be careful as `'hello' == 'hello'`, but `'hello' is not 'hello'`

Comment: @polvoazul -- Actually, that depends on your python implementation.  In Cpython, often `'hello' is 'hello'` _will_ be `True`, but that's not behavior that is guaranteed and so you shouldn't rely on it. :-)

Comment: Alternatively you could avoid the question all together and do ```if not match``` which will evaluate ```True``` since ```bool(None)``` is ```False```

Comment: @wnnmaw but if match will have position 0? Btw, i should use `if match:` in my case, right?

Comment: I will answer my question: Yes, it just should be `if match`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject

Comment: @avasin, right, point is you can avoid using ```==``` or ```is``` all together

Comment: @mgilson -- Thats very correct, it will actually be true as I think Cpython keeps small strings as singletons, but as you said we should not rely on this! For curiosity, in cpython3.3: `print(20*'a' is 20*'a') => True` but 
`print(21*'a' is 21*'a') => False`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

Comment: @AaronHall You can create your own singletons  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558/python-and-the-singleton-pattern  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python

Comment: That might be better if added to your answer, lest it be interpreted differently.